# InDesign Merge Data Text width fit frame width and not the opposite

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs6

Good Evening,

I would like to have my text width stretching automatically to its Text frame in InDesign CS6. 
(I want the text adapting to the frame and not the frame adapting to the text) 
So the text will have the same width even if it is a bit stretched.
Is it something we can do ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean? The text will flow in the text box. Unless what you mean is that you want the letters themselves to stretch? :S